# Setting time/date field value properly via Tivoli Directory Integrator

Tags: date, lotus-notes, lotus, tivoli

Could anyone help me find out how to set a time/date field properly in Lotus Notes database via Tivoli Directory Integrator?
I added a new date field to Person form in names.nsf. TDI is set up correctly to sync data from MS AD to Domino Directory. There's a text field in MS AD containing a date in the following format: "YYYY.MM.DD". I want this field also to be synced.
The value is set in Domino by TDI, but when I try to open and save the document containing he synced value in Notes, it doesn't allow saving the document due to invalid date format.

Comment: Can you post the details about the field. I would be interested in seeing the document properties with that field.